# What does this key error mean when calling MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod?

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic

Today I got this error from some old dynamic casting code (I have changed the last line and left out the rest of the stack trace):

```
Item has already been added. 
Key in dictionary: 
   'Int32 Count[Object](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object])'  
Key being added: 
   'Int32 Count[Object](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object])' 
---> System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. 
     Key in dictionary: 
         'Int32 Count[Object](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object])'  
     Key being added: 
         'Int32 Count[Object](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object])'
  at System.Reflection.CerHashtable`2.Insert(K[] keys, V[] values, Int32& count, K key, V value)
  at System.Reflection.CerHashtable`2.Preallocate(Int32 count)
  at System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.GetGenericMethodInfo(RuntimeMethodHandle genericMethod)
  at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodBase(RuntimeTypeHandle reflectedTypeHandle, RuntimeMethodHandle methodHandle)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[] methodInstantiation)
  at MyNamespace.CommunicationExtensions.BuildMessage[T](T obj)
```

The full class

```
public static class CommunicationExtensions {
    static readonly object lockobj = new object();
    public static bool CanBuildMessage<T>(this T obj) where T: class {
        return obj != null && (MessageFactory.MessageBuilders.ContainsKey(obj.GetType()));
    }
    public static string BuildMessage<T>(this T obj) {
        lock (lockobj) {
            Delegate d;
            var type = obj.GetType();

            if (MessageFactory.MessageBuilders.TryGetValue(type, out d)) {
                var castMethod = typeof(CommunicationExtensions).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(type);
                var castedObject = castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { obj });

                return d.DynamicInvoke(castedObject) as string;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static T Cast<T>(object o) {
        return (T)o;
    }
}
```

`MessageFactory.MessageBuilders` is a `Dictionary<Type,Func<Type,string>>` containing compiled lambda expressions that are lazily built as needed to convert the Message events (simple auto-property classes based on EventArgs) into a string format used in other systems. I don't think any of that matters though. I think the only code necessary to cause this issue is:

```
public static class CastError{
    public static void GetCast<T>(this T obj) {
        var type = obj.GetType();
        var castMethod = typeof(CastError).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(type);
        //...
    }
    public static T Cast<T>(object o) {
        return (T)o;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's ugly.  Looks like a framework bug to me.  MethodInfo is documented to be thread safe.  Is this multithreaded code?

Comment: yeah, the DynamicInvoke there calls something that is not necessarily thread safe though (the get methods on the classes that are being converted can do anything).

Comment: @BillBarry thats true but the stack trace explicitly shows this error coming from the MakeGenericMethod call...

Comment: Just explaining why the lock is there...

Comment: @BillBarry - Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @BillBarry - Are you able to tell what `T` is when the exception occurs as well as every run before it? I've been digging through the code for the methods listed in your stack trace and it is definitely thread safe (2 layers of `Monitor` locks).

Comment: In the 3 different stack traces I have found, the type passed in to MakeGenericMethod is `string`, a particular subclass of `EventArgs` and one of these: `string`, `int`, or 4 enum types. I have found other stack traces where MakeGenericMethod is called and the stack trace is the same from there in. In this particular class only the one subclass of EventArgs is passed in causing the error.  I can also say that `string` doesn't trigger it every time because I know of cases where it must be getting `string` and it works.

Comment: Btw, recycling the application (ASP.NET) made the error go away and I can no longer reproduce it. I still need to be able to explain what happened though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it looks like is a failure in the framework to lock properly in the internals of MakeGenericMethod.

When MakeGenericMethod is called, the framework is supposed to either create a new version of the method with the generic parameters specified, or if the same generic parameter type(s) have been used before to create that generic method then it should return the previously-generated method.  It looks like you hit an edge case where calling `MakeGenericMethod` on multiple threads can result in a race condition where both threads think that the method has not yet been generated and go ahead and generate it, then subsequently conflict in storing the generated methods for future calls.

That said, in this case it looks like it's all in a lock, so I am not fully convinced that this is the problem either.

I'd file it with MSFT as a bug, unless someone else can explain how this is expected behavior.

Comment: I've faced the bug too in .NET 4.0 and filed it as https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/738253