# Linq-To-Sql lambda chain sporadically causing 'Item has already been added' exception originating from System.RuntimeTypeCache.GetGenericMethodInfo

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

Recently we have received error reports from two customers with the following stack trace (our namespace has been replaced with *****):

```
[ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Boolean Single[Boolean](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Boolean])'  Key being added: 'Boolean Single[Boolean](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Boolean])']
System.Reflection.CerHashtable`2.Insert(K[] keys, V[] values, Int32& count, K key, V value) +9600475
System.Reflection.CerHashtable`2.Preallocate(Int32 count) +307
System.RuntimeTypeCache.GetGenericMethodInfo(RuntimeMethodHandleInternal genericMethod) +299
System.RuntimeType.GetMethodBase(RuntimeType reflectedType, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal methodHandle) +543
System.RuntimeType.GetMethodBase(RuntimeType reflectedType, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle) +25
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(RuntimeMethodHandle handle) +27
*****.Core.Repositories.Common.IsThereAnAuthorizedUserManager() +383
*****.Client.Host.WebLogin.Login.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +334
System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

The IsThereAnAuthorizedUserManager() function is as follows:

```
public bool IsThereAnAuthorizedUserManager()
{
    return context.Users.Any(u => u.IsEnabled && u.DeletionDate == null && u.UserRoles.Any(ur => ur.Role.RoleOperations.Any(ro => ro.OperationType == (int)OperationType.ManageUsers)));
}
```

The SQL that is output from this statement is as follows:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
(CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [dbo].[User] AS [t0]
        WHERE ([t0].[IsEnabled] = 1) AND ([t0].[DeletionDate] IS NULL) AND (EXISTS(
            SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
            FROM [dbo].[UserRole] AS [t1]
            WHERE (EXISTS(
                SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
                FROM [dbo].[Role] AS [t2], [dbo].[RoleOperation] AS [t3]
                WHERE ([t3].[OperationType] = @p0) AND ([t2].[RoleID] = [t1].[RoleID]) AND ([t3].[RoleID] = [t2].[RoleID])
                )) AND ([t1].[UserID] = [t0].[UserID])
            ))
        ) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
 END) AS [value]',N'@p0 int',@p0=102
```

.Any() should always return a single boolean result, so I'm unsure how this would result in the error being thrown. We have yet to be able to reproduce it in testing, and it seems to be fixed by having the user reset IIS.

Is there an inherent problem with chaining .Any() in this way? Or perhaps something else we are doing wrong that I'm just not seeing? Our current plan for a 'fix' is going to be to replace the statement with a call to a scalar-value SQL function that will perform the same logic without the need for the .NET Framework to get involved, but this seems like it shouldn't be necessary.

For reference, this does seem very similar to this question: [What does this key error mean when calling MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419464/what-does-this-key-error-mean-when-calling-methodinfo-makegenericmethod)